# How to convert date in format mm/yy from character to date class?

Tags: r, class, date

Just a brief (and hopefully simple!) question;

I have a column of dates such as `08/14` and `08/15`. However the column class is `character`, and I was wondering if it is possible (and if so how) to convert this into a date class? I've tried lots of different ways and it either does nothing, or returns `N/A` values for the whole column. Hopefully there should be a simple line of code to fix this that I haven't come across yet?

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a day by `paste`ing and then use `as.Date` because date also needs day info

```
as.Date(paste0(c("08/14", "08/15"), "/01"), format = "%m/%y/%d")
#[1] "2014-08-01" "2015-08-01"
```

---

Or make use of `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(c("08/14", "08/15"), "%m/%y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
dates <- c("08/14", "10/13", "12/09") # year-month
datesWithYear <- paste(date, "/01", sep = "") %>%
                   as.Date()
```

If you want to use the year-month combination as a factor for cohort analysis of something similar you can always use `as.yearmon()` from the `zoo` package. `tsibble` and `lubridate` also have interesting functions for dealing with dates and time.